# What are the most (and least) likely factors of a composite Mersenne number?

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization, mersenne-numbers

> What are the most (and least) likely factors of a composite Mersenne number?

Suppose some number $M_p=2^p-1:p\in\text{prime}$ is a candidate for a Lucas Lehmer test.  Is it possible to identify a set of the most-likely factors for pre-sieving before starting?

EDIT: A comment says factors of $M_p$ must be of the form $2kp+1$, so are there subsets of those which cannot be, or are less- or more-likely to be factors?

Comment: It certainly won't be $3$, $5$ or $7$ if $p > 4$.

Comment: For a prime $p$, a prime divisor of $2^p-1$ must be of the form $2kp + 1$. If you get candidates from GIMPS, this type of sieving is already certainly done there.

Comment: If $p$ is an odd prime, the factors also must be of the form $8k\pm 1$

Comment: dependent on $p$ even for the subset ...